firewalld port forward as policy
I am able to port forward with firewalld with the following commands:
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=443:proto=tcp:toport=443:toaddr=192.168.23.26
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload

But I would like to do exactly the same thing with a policy (for ease of deleting in a script). I've tried the following:
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy=aecitools-in
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=aecitools-in --add-ingress-zone=external
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=aecitools-in --add-egress-zone=internal
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=aecitools-in --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=aecitools-in --add-forward-port=port=443:proto=tcp:toport=443:toaddr=192.168.23.26
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=aecitools-in --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload

But this gives the following error:
Error: INVALID_ZONE: Policy 'aecitools-in': 'forward-port' cannot be used because egress zone 'internal' has assigned interfaces

If I omit the line adding an egress zone, I don't get errors, but port forwarding doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?
